# Why have I silently lost ~250 rep points?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

Late this afternoon, my rep was at 9900-something.
I just peeked in, and the main and meta sites report me at 9713.

I'm less concerned about the number itself than why, unless it's actually just some error. There are no deductions being reported anywhere that I can see, either as downvotes(which would take a lot) or flags(assuming I could see that, and they go in 100 increments anyway). They're just gone for no apparent reason.

Here's a screenshot from the [site leagues page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/9/alltime/webmasters/2008-12-05/4502#4502), with more or less what I'm expecting to see: [image]

Comment: A review of your [network stats](http://stackexchange.com/users/241686/su?tab=reputation) confirms your suspicion, however, I can see where at least 20 points have migrated from Webmasters.SE to WordPress.SE within the last 24 hours - there have been a good number of migrations recently, so my best recommendation would be to see whether the missing rep shows up on other SE sites. (Perhaps the rep reassignment is delayed on migrations?)

Comment: Yeah, the 20 was [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42677/wordpress-queue-like-tumblr/42678#42678) but that happened–and I saw the drop–way back in the morning, before this. There does seem to be something weird going on. I just spotted that my accounts list over at [my SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/512657/su) actually reports a *higher* webmasters rep than even in my screenshot. Let's leave it a day or so and see if whatever it is self-corrects.

Comment: Okay, so it's been a couple days, the network stats are now tracking my current rep count with no indication the missing points ever existed, and the SO profile is also current. Next steps, or do I just eat this?

Comment: I still suspect your rep is now associated with a different SE, but you're already signed up on most of the likely ones. Could you try setting up an account at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) to determine whether some of rep was moved there? (Beyond that, I believe an SE employee would be best-equipped to help with this issue)

Comment: I'm looking into this. So far I can reasonably certainly say this is not a bug, but I'm still tracking down the explanation. (cc @danlefree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reputation was recalculated by a scheduled service that accumulates reasons to perform a recalc over time.

Far as I can tell, what happened was that one of your answers got migrated away to Wordpress and the migration stub left behind was deleted. (Aside: the original URL to the question on Webmasters now redirects to Wordpress, so we don't keep migration stubs around for very long.)

This triggered a recalculation of your rep, which then picked up a bunch of deleted answers that you had and adjusted your reputation accordingly.

Comment: Ah. I'd never seen such a large deduction come out of nowhere, so was confused. Thanks for digging into this.